# setting up a range from 1 to n

Tags: python, pandas, range

I'm looping through the sheets of an excel, transform them and append them in a single dataset. The lenght of the n of sheets might change from file to file, therefore I need to set up a range from 1 (i don't need the first sheet) to n.. how do I do it?

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for i in range(1:):
    df_1 = pd.read_csv(pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\filippo.sebastio\OneDrive - ELEVATE\Target\Target Download 28 Feb\Quantitative data\SCHAEFER_Putian ZhangSheng\zhangsheng  --   RSAP Factory Metrics Tool- Hardcopy Form draft to publish 2018 12.xlsx', i , header = 4, index_col=1), index_col=None, header=0)
    worksheet_1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
    df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.index[0])
    df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.index[-1])
    df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.columns[0], axis=1)
    df_1 = df_1.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
    for col in  df_1.columns[0:3]:
        df_1[col] = pd.to_numeric(df_1[col], errors='coerce')
    df_1['mean'] = df_1.iloc[:, 0:3].mean(axis=1)
    df_1 = df_1[[ 'mean']]
    df_1_t = df_1.T
    df_1_t['Month'] = worksheet_1.cell(5, 2).value 
    df_1_t['Factory'] = worksheet_0.cell(2,2 ).value
    df_1_t['Factory_id'] = worksheet_0.cell(3,2 ).value
    df_1_t['Country'] = worksheet_0.cell(4,2 ).value
    df_1_t['Consultant'] = worksheet_0.cell(5,2 ).value

    list_.append(df1_t)

frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

I am currently getting this error

```
  File "<ipython-input-173-15bf28de4a3b>", line 4
    for i in range(1:):
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use `for i in range(n)` to iterate from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: `range(start,stop,step)` is the function

Comment: I need to iterate from 1 to n, for i in rane(1:n) gives me the same error result

Answer (score 0):

The ':' refer to the slicing of arrays/lists in Python.  For example:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print data[1:]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

but what you need is:

```
for i in range(n, m):  # no double point, only comma!
```

an iterator over a list of integers from `n` to `m-1`.

Comment: Silly me!, that's true! Thanks!

Comment: Richard i would I write it though? for i in range(1,-1): doesn't work - I don't manage to iterate through the sheets..

Comment: write " for i in range(1, lenght_of_smt): " , and the length should be bigger then 1.